# Trying to retrofit values from lists to return multiple solutions

Tags: c#, algorithm

This is a bit of weird requirement so bear with me.

I have two values, X and Y, that come from three possible range lists.  One list is a range for X values, one list is a range for Y values and the final list is ranges for X and Y values combined.

What I need to do is to find all possible solutions.

An example will probably make things clearer?

## X Ranges

A: 11-13;
B: 14-16;
C: 17-19;
D: 20-22.

## Y Ranges

A: 11-28;
B: 29-46;
C: 47-64.

## X, Y Ranges

A: 6-7, 6-14;
B: 8-9, 15-23;
C: 10-11, 24-32.

X = 25, Y = 67

So one solution would be:

- X Range = B, X = 14
- Y Range = B, Y = 35
- X, Y Range = C, X, Y = 11, 32

Another solution would be:

- X Range = B, X = 15
- Y Range = B, Y = 43
- X, Y Range = C, X, Y = 10, 24

My current solution is to put the three ranges into lists and then to use brute force to try EVERY single combination, rejecting any that don't give the correct answer.  This means that the vast majority of the solution is taken up generating invalid results.

This actually performs not too badly considering the wasted effort.  The problem is I need to get this working for much longer lists than my example and potentially across multiple variables.

My brute force solution will work for the more complicated requirement but it starts to get really slow.

is there a more elegant way to approach this problem?

Comment: Would ordering the ranges help, by low-limit perhaps, such that you could drop out of a loop early?

Comment: Yes, that would help and there are probably other things I could do to make the brute force solution work more efficiently.  However, I was really hoping there was something I was missing here and there was a fundamentally better way to do this.

Comment: So you first build all combinations of the lists, then second reject wrong answers? Could you reverse those steps?

Answer (score 0):

1.The problem specification

- I am not sure I follow your solutions so for clarification:
- i assume X=25,Y=67 is input value
- but not X nor Y is inside any of your input ranges
- are you finding any X,Y <0-max value provided as input>
- that matches some X,Y,XY range at the same time ?

2.so you need to speedup finding of overlapping intervals

- to speed up search in list you can use sorted lists
- for each range list create 2 index lists
- one sorted by start ascending
- second sorted by stop value descending
- also after this you can implement binary search
- example:

  ```
  range list:   A(1-10), B(5-7), C(22-30), D(5-8)
  sorted list1: A, B, D, C
  sorted list2: C, A, D, B
  ```
- now I want to find all intervals which covers value 10
- so make 2 list of solutions, one for each sorted lists

  ```
  start <= 10: A,B,D
  stop  >= 10: A,C
  ```
- now the solution is to select just ranges found in both list

  ```
  solution: A
  ```
- you can adapt this to your problem
- at first look this seems like slower more complicated approach
- but thanks to binary search the search can be quick
- and you do not realy have to have 2 solution lists in memory they are really just 2 start indexes
- one for each sorted index list